# How to get a system bundle fragment version at runtime

Tags: osgi, equinox

I've created a system bundle fragment for a host bundle using this:

```
Fragment-Host: system.bundle;extension:=framework
```

I would like to know the version of the fragment inside the system bundle activator method. there is way to get that ?

If I use the context parameter of the activator method I can get the system bundle but couldn't find how to get its fragments...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check OSGi Core Spec 5.0 (7.2.x chapter)

```
  BundleWiring wA = systemBundleContext.getBundle().adapt( BundleWiring.class );
  for ( BundleWire wire : wA.getProvidedWires(HOST_NAMESPACE)) {
    // fragment bundle version
    wire.getRequirerWiring().getResource().getVersion();
  }
```

Comment: Hi, wiring framework seems powerful but not that trivial :). I found that wire.getRequirer().getVersion() can be used too. thanks